# A Dozen Cubic Miles of Volcanic Ash--How Big Would the Cloud Be?

Tags: internal-consistency, hard-science, natural-disasters, volcanoes

On May 18, 1980, Mount Saint Helens made American history with an eruption that took 57 human lives and killed thousands of animals.  It has released only a quarter of a cubic mile of ash, but it is the influence of the prevailing winds that allows us to measure the area and thickness of the ash cloud. The prevailing winds of 1980 made the Mount Saint Helens ash cloud a bit like this:

[image]

The reason I brought it up is that it inspired this particular alternate scenario.  In an alternate Earth, there is a volcanic island six miles wide and 8,157 feet above sea level.  It is located 42°54′59″N but 50 miles west of the coast.  Let us say that this fictional volcanic island, which I'd christened "Wizard Island", was the alternate volcano that erupted in 1980, not Mount Saint Helens.  It's not just the different location of the eruption that would affect the outcome of the question, but also the different volume of the eruption.  Wizard Island erupted a dozen cubic miles of ash, 48 times bigger than Mount Saint Helens in OTL.  Using the provided information, how big and how thick would the resulting ash cloud be?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94043/discussion-on-question-by-johnwdailey-a-dozen-cubic-miles-of-volcanic-ash-how-b).

Answer (score 6):

First you have a problem 50 miles off the coast is solidly on oceanic crust. volcanoes that pop out of the oceanic crust are not releasing a lot of ash, As oceanic crust is  mostly basalt so is the laval. thus they tend toward [basaltic lava type volcanoes instead](http://www.tulane.edu/~sanelson/Natural_Disasters/volcan&magma.htm). You need a more rhyolitic composition to get a lot of ash. This means you are going to need to do some serious changes to the underlying tectonics so no exact match is possible.

for your ejecta volume look as similar volcanoes on the [eruption scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volcanic_Explosivity_Index).

The more basaltic the lava the less of the ejecta will be ash. A basaltic volcanic eruption will be one of the largest in earths history to generate that much ash, and will be heard across the entire planet and cause massive tsunami. looking at 1815 eruption of [Mount Tambora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1815_eruption_of_Mount_Tambora) sizes, which created the year without a summer and will seriously screw over human civilization. And that's on the low end, on hte high end something closer to the deccan traps in size. so expect the end of human civilization and the one of hte largest mass extinctions in history.

But honestly things like how the eruption occurs and over what time scale it occurs can change this greatly so even this is just a ballpark. If you somehow get a motre rhyolitic volcano you are looking at something closer to the The Mount [Pinatubo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Pinatubo) eruption which will still be quite massive. A complete review of the eruption ashfall can be found [here.](https://pubs.geoscienceworld.org/gsa/geology/article-abstract/23/10/885/206170)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is a very close real-life example.  The climactic eruption of Mt. Mazama that created Oregon's Crater Lake (which perhaps coincidentally contains Wizard Island) ejected an estimated 12-14 cubic miles of material: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Mazama#Climactic_eruption  The distribution of that material is well-mapped - the layer is even used to date prehistoric objects, since the date of the eruption is fairly accurately known.

Here's a link to a map of the ash fall: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Estimated-spatial-distribution-of-Mt-Mazama-volcanic-ash-across-the-western-United_fig1_265168566 Just offset it to the location of your "Wizard Island", and you'll have something realistic.  (But note what others have said about the realism of this kind of volcano being found off the Pacific Coast.)  You could also change the wind direction somewhat.  Mazama's winds seem to have been to the northeast, while Mt. St. Helens' were a bit southerly.

Comment: Mazama ejected 12-14 miles of LAVA (mostly pumice) not ash that is very different type of eruption.

Comment: @John: Not according to the articles I've read, for instance the Wikipedia link.  From what I've read and know of the geology of the area, Mazama was a typical Cascade volcano, very similar to St. Helens.

Comment: Cascade volcano has nothing to do with the type of eruption. Cascade is a reference to the layout of the volcano and the surrounding terrain not the composition of the volcano. It being a cascade volcano means it is part of a subduction mountain arc.

Comment: Mazama erupted volcanic ash as well as pumice and other typical material. That it is why it is called Mazama Ash. And it's called a "Cascade Volcano" because it is in the Cascade Range and has nothing to do with the "layout of the volcano" whatever that means. The statement that it's typical Cascade volcano means it is typical of volcanoes found in the Cascades, like St. Helens. Which it was. https://pubs.usgs.gov/fs/2002/fs092-02/

Comment: @John: If the Mazama eruption had produced 12 cubic miles of lava, it would still be THERE.  Instead, there's a great big hole (partly filled with water) where there used to be a ~12,000 ft mountain peak: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crater_Lake_National_Park

Comment: You do realized there are more options than just basaltic lava and ash right?

Comment: @KeithMorrison being part of a cascade range would be part of its layout, how it is positioned in the surrounding terrain. and being part of a cascade range does not tell you what it produces there are many types of volcanoes in the cascades with many eruption types. Mazama is a combination of shield and srtato-volcano. It produces many kinds of eruptions, the 12-14 cubic miles  in the linked paper is the total combined output most of the mass of which is pumice ans other lavas. was there ash sure almost any kind of eruption can produce some ash. Mazama is a really weird volcano.

Comment: @John, that is not what "Cascade" means, and no geologist (of which I am one) has ever used it in the way you describe at any time I have ever heard. Secondly, look up "Mazama Ash" on Wikipedia.

Comment: @KeithMorrison Cascade volcano refers to it being part of a cascade range or an arc of mountains formed by a subduction zone. I don't understand what you are confused by? I have been checking the paper os Mazama and I was wrong, there was around a dozen 13-17) cubic miles of ash from the eruption even if the primary product was not ash.  I was thrown off because the estimated pumice from the eruption was 12-14 cubic miles with another dozen cubic miles of other solids. So even if jamesqf was quoting the wrong numbers they were correct  about it being the right size.

Comment: The Mazama eruption is weird, a switching eruption type  part way through an eruption is just strange. I'm glad this made me look into it more thoroughly. @jamesqf please edit your answer so I can remove my downvote.

Comment: @John: 1) When I wrote "typical Cascade volcano", all I meant was that it was/is typical of the other volcanos in the Cascade range, nothing more.  I am not a geologist, and was not using it as a geological term.  2) And likewise with "ash" (which of course is a misnomer anyway, as it's not the product of burning).  I meant stuff that gets blasted into the air and carried by wind.  I don't care if you want to call it "pumice", and really don't see that there's a non-technical difference.

Comment: @jamesqf pumice and volcanic ash (volcanic ash is a fine term by the way) are different things the stuff blown into the air is not pumice, pumice is basically very foamy lava, if it has more gas you get ash. Mazama erupted both ,as well as a few other things. My point is there is no such thing as a typical cascade volcano, nearly every form of volcano occurs in the cascade ranges. When I asked you to edit your post I meant any kind of edit, you cant retract a down vote if more than a day has passed unless the answer is edited. I want to retract the down vote and cannot.

Comment: @John: I think the difference between pumice & ash really isn't relevant in the context of the OP's question, as he's just asking about the cloud of stuff that gets blown downwind.  With Mazama (and more recently St. Helens) that "stuff" would also seem to include a big chunk of the actual mountain, not just magma/lava/ash erupted at the time.

Comment: Part of the confusion here is apparently the belief that "volcanic ash" is different from the other stuff that comes out of an erupting volcano. It is not. "Ash" is merely a generic name for the pulverized material that is smaller than 2mm. It could be volcanic glass, it can be fragments of pahoehoe or aa, clasts that get smashed up and yes, fragments of pumice.